# Measure to calculate current closed risks

Tags: powerbi, calendar, powerbi-desktop, measure, powerbi-filters

I need help with a measure to calculate current closed risks. I have the risk table linked to the calendar[Date] table with an active relationship in Creation Date and one inactive for Mitigation Date (Closing risk date).
The measure I use is the following:

`Mitigated risks = var selectedDate = Max('Calendar[Date]) VAr FilteredTable = Filter('Risk', 'Risk'[Mitigation Date] <= selectedDate && 'Risk'[Mitigated]="Mitigated") RETURN Countrows(FilteredTable)`

This measure works ok, but when I use it in a visual and filter by a slicer with Calendar[Date] as the field, it behaves strangely.
If I select the first semester (H2 2021), it displays the correct count of closed risks,

if I select the next semester (H1 2022), it goes blank and it is blank for all subsequent semesters.

This shows that the measure works with the first date in the slicer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0wsQ.png)

This is to show that starting from the next semester in the slicer, the measure goes blank.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hdzi.png)

What is missing in the measure so that it displays the correct count for each semester?
Any help is appreciated.

Tables:

| Risk Id | Creation Semester |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 H2 |
| 2 | 2021 H2 |
| 3 | 2022 H1 |
| 4 | 2022 H1 |
| 5 | 2022 H2 |
| 6 | 2022 H2 |

| Creation Date | Mitigation Semester |
| --- | --- |
| 31/12/2021 | 2022 H1 |
| 31/12/2021 | 2021 H2 |
| 30/06/2022 | 2022 H1 |
| 30/06/2022 | 2022 H2 |
| 31/12/2022 |  |
| 31/12/2022 | 2023 H1 |

| Mitigation Date | Mitigated |
| --- | --- |
| 30/06/2022 | Mitigated |
| 31/12/2021 | Mitigated |
| 30/06/2022 | Mitigated |
| 31/12/2022 | Mitigated |
|  | Open |
| 30/06/2023 | Mitigated |

Edit: if I add 'ALL' to the measure, it works ok for the semester. But if I add it to bar chart with risk owner on the other axis, I get the same total per each user.

Mitigated risks = var selectedDate = Max('Calendar[Date]) VAr FilteredTable = Filter(ALL('Risk'), 'Risk'[Mitigation Date] <= selectedDate && 'Risk'[Mitigated]="Mitigated") RETURN Countrows(FilteredTable)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxae9.png)

Comment: I tested your code. Its working fine. Issue is not with code. Check any other filters applied on visual

Comment: Change the date format to month/date/year and check

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ABout changing the date format I am not sure if it will work as I have other measures like Current Open Risks that use the same date format as the Mitigated measure and it works ok. 
Do I need to change the date format on all my date columns in the dataset?

Comment: Also, why should work for the first semester in the slicer and not for the others semesters if it was a date issue?

Comment: I used your tables, created `CALENDARAUTO()` for Date column, created relationships to Creation Date (Active), Mitigation Date (Inactive). It worked for me. My Date format is in month/date/year. I guess date format has no effect. Hover over `Filter on Visual` and see any other filters applied on visual.

Comment: Hi, not sure if I was clear in my post. When I say I want to display the current closed risks, I mean not only the ones closed in the semester selected in the calendar, but also those ones closed in the previous semesters.

Comment: This measure works ok in a visual card:

Mitigated risks = var selectedDate = Max('Calendar[Date]) VAr FilteredTable = Filter(ALL('Risk'), 'Risk'[Mitigation Date] <= selectedDate && 'Risk'[Mitigated]="Mitigated") RETURN Countrows(FilteredTable)

But  if I use it in a table with risk owner, it will display the total (for example 22) per each owner, instead of dividing the 22 among the owners. How can I fix that please?